# How to make the email app on iOS work like Gmail app?

Tags: iphone, ios, mail.app, mobile-mail

I tried searching for `Macy's e-receipt` by typing in `Macy receipt` on my Mac using Gmail, and the result came back in 1 second. (some of those emails were 1 month old, and another one 2 months old).

But when I tried that using the email app on iPhone with iOS 6.1.4, nothing came back, and I click "Subject", and I changed the keyword to `Macy's e-receipt` and clicked "Continue Search on Server..." and it just kept on turning the spinning wheel for 2 minutes and nothing came back.

And then I searched for and installed the Gmail app on the iPhone, and type in `Macy receipt` and the result came back in 1 second.

So how do I make the email app standard on iOS work like Gmail's search?

Comment: @tubedogg does that question tell you how to make the email app work like Gmail's app or does it tell you to just use the Gmail app instead?

Comment: The underlying issue is that Mail.app's search appears to be broken when using it on a Gmail account. There is no way to fix that short of re-engineering Mail.app, which unless you work at Apple is not going to be possible.